# warning: conversion to 'u8int' from 'int' may alter its value, etc

Tags: c

So lately I've been writing stuff where I have to use a lot of uint8/uint16 and mix them with each other and integer literals. So I'm getting warnings such as:

```
warning: conversion to 'u16int' from 'int' may alter its value
```

Code:

```
u16int attr = attr_byte << 8;
```

I like compiling with lots of warnings on. I do not like getting warnings. Is there some (preferably clean) way to fix this?

Comment: You should really make `attr_byte` an unsigned int, because shifting does not work as you think it does.

Comment: The warning makes sense, because an `int` is signed, while `u16int` interprets what it contains as unsigned. This leads to a problem - how to interpret the result where a value-bit becomes a sign-bit?

Comment: @amn: Even worse: Shifting signed values is implementation dependent.

Comment: @ouah I suspect it's a 32-bit floating-point type. Or a pointer to an incomplete struct type. (Do you know the Latin proverb 'Nomen est omen'?)

Comment: @ouah partly right. However, if `u16int` is not a 16-bit unsigned integer, one should probably not use this typedef.

Comment: attr_byte is already unsigned, it's u8int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard says that the "integer promotions" are performed on each of the operands and that the type of the result is that of the promoted left operand (C99 §6.5.7/3).

The integer promotions (§6.3.1.1/2) say that if an `int` can represent all of the possible values, then it's promoted to an `int`.  So, assuming that `attr_byte` is one byte, it can fit an `int`, so it's promoted to an `int`.  Thus, the result of the left shift is a (signed) `int`, so the compiler is right to complain that the conversion from `int` to `u16int` may alter its value.

In this instance, the result of the left shift will never be larger than 0xFF00 or less than 0, so there won't be any data loss.  But if you don't want the compiler to warn you here, you need to cast the result to `u16int`, since the result of the shift will always be an `int` or `unsigned int` (or a larger integer type), regardless of the types of its operands.

Comment: So if I understand well, the correct line should be : `u16int attr = (u16int)((unsigned int)attr_byte << 8);` ? Or is it rather `u16int attr = (u16int)(((unsigned int)attr_byte << 8) & 0xFFFF);` ?

Comment: Just `u16int attr = (u16int)(attr_byte << 8)` is sufficient.  The extra casts on the inside don't change anything in this case and just clutter up the code.

Comment: 1) according to ouah answer, binary shift must be done on unsigned type only, but default integer promotion is to signed int, hence the need for a manual unsigned cast. Correct ?

Comment: 2) so a cast from a bigger int to a smaller one is always done by taking the last significant bits ? Confirm ?

Answer (score 4):

You can always cast:

```
u16int attr = (u16int)(attr_byte << 8);
```

I.e. you tell the compiler you know what you are doing.

Comment: I'd rather not do this. Signed shifting does not work as OP expects it to work.

Comment: Might be my only choice... but it's so ugly.

Answer (score 2):

```
u16int attr = ((unsigned int) attr_byte << 8);
```

You should bitwise shift only unsigned types.

C Standard does not require any diagnostic for the declaration above but if your compiler is too verbose you can add an extra `uint16_t` cast to the bitwise shift expression.

Comment: It already is unsigned. The int that GCC is complaining about here (I believe) is the literal 8. Either that or GCC is acting strangely and not mentioning that it's unsigned.

Comment: @Knyght if `attr_byte` is `unsigned char` it is promoted to `int` in the `<<` expression. Now the `8` (i.e., the right operand of the `<<` operator`) has strictly no influence on the resulting type of the `<<` expression: the resulting type of the `<<` operation is that of the promoted left operand of `<<`.